# SQL - Selecting all or none in a set of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table where multiple entries are grouped by having the same number. Each of these rows also have a result.

Example

```
id 4 | Group 5 | Result 1
id 5 | Group 5 | Result 1
id 6 | Group 6 | Result 0
id 7 | Group 6 | Result 1
```

How would I go about selecting the highest number group where all their result is the same number?

In otherwords, say I want to get the highest group where `result = 1`; I would not want group 6 as there is a result is 0, nor would I want any groups older than group 4 as all of group 5 have a result of 1.

Comment: What's your dbms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of different ways to do this.  Here's one approach to select the highest `group` using `order by` and `limit` where all results are `1` using `max` and `min`:

```
select grp
from yourtable
group by grp
having max(result) = 1 and min(result) = 1
order by grp desc
limit 1
```

Comment: This worked. I added:"select * from table where result = (<Your sql string>)" --- and got the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly dierent approach.

```
SELECT `group` FROM `test` 
GROUP BY `group`
HAVING COUNT(`result`)=SUM(`result`) AND SUM(`result`)>0
ORDER BY `group` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Check it on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/924b55/7)